# Twitter Bootstrap: Select Box vs DropDown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple code from bootstrap for selection

```
<select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
</select>
```

This gives a select box  with drop down options 1,2,3,4 and 5. but the value displayed in select box is **1**. I want to display the select box with title **"Select number"** and in that drop down the values should be 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Crude way to do that is add

```
        <option>Select number</option>
```

Is there a better way such that I can display Select Number in select box but not on the list of list box.?

Thanks

Comment: 'coz web is what you make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hide that option in CSS.

**CSS :**

```
.form-control option:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SUTX5/)

**NOTE** : Once they select any option, they can't go back (Using a mouse). Keyboard rocks!

---

**EDIT:**

You can change your HTML to contain

```
<option disabled selected>Select number</option>
```

so that once they select any option, they can't go back at all !

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akki06/CDByj/)

Comment: They can go back using the keyboard and can submit 'selected' as a value. Its just that they cant see it.

Comment: @akki: why not put that in your own answer?

Comment: My idea was to make one complete answer for the question and I chose yours for that since I have upvoted your answer myself ;)

Comment: I like to see `value` attribute with `option` elements set to something to get consistent results at the server side when coming from different browsers.

Comment: You can set a value for this one too

Comment: I'll let you do the honours! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
<option disabled selected="selected">Select number</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jquery code for you.

```
function updateMenu() {
    $('.form-control').prepend('<option value="0">Select Number</option>');
    $(".form-control option:first").attr('selected','selected');
}

//initialize
$(function(){
   updateMenu();
});

//Make changes on hover
$('.form-control').hover(
    function(){
       $('option[value="0"]', this).remove(); 
    }, updateMenu 
);
```

Comment: ;) making the world a better place to live.